# VBA - how to do "save as" with reference to other open workbook's "cell value" in "file name"

Tags: excel, vba

Need help to create VBA code to do "save as" with reference to other open workbook's "cell value" in "file name".

Comment: You will have to provide more information (like the value in cell A1 will be the name, the extension will be .xlsx, the name of the open workbook is test.xlsm or starts with "Book" or is unknown and stuff like that) and provide the code you have tried to get good (any) answers. There is an edit button below your post which you can use to update your question.

Comment: Resolved with following code    Dim monthname As String
monthname = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _
        "E:\Personal\" & monthname & "  - Combine Data.xlsb" _
        , FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False , Thanks for prompt reply..

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you really want to keep the data file open, if not, you can use the ExecuteExcel4Macro method :

```
monthname = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\FolderPath\[Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!" & _
            Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
```

Here is my function :

```
'### The xl file can be closed or open ###
Function getValueInWB( _
                        folderPath As String, _
                        fileName As String, _
                        shName As String, _
                        rAdd As String _
                        )

    Dim str As String

    str = "'" & folderPath & _
            "[" & fileName & "]" & _
            shName & "'!" & _
            Range(rAdd).Address(, , xlR1C1)

    getValueInWB = ExecuteExcel4Macro(str)

End Function
```

Test function :

```
Function testPrintValue()

    folderPath = "C:\FolderPath\"
    fileName = "Data.xlsx"
    shName = "Sheet1"
    rAdd = "A1"

    getValueInWB folderPath , fileName, shName, rAdd

End Function
```